# Incorrect encoding in unicode post

Tags: android, post, unicode, urlencode

I try to send http post with russian letters to webpage.

So, I send password `"руский"` that in Chrome Developer Tool shown as `"%F0%F3%F1%EA%E8%E9"` , but when I sen it from the phone, I get `"%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9"`.

So, what encode I need to use in my post?

P.s I am not Russian

**Here is code**

```
public void postData(String login, String password, int enter) throws URISyntaxException {
        HttpPost httppost = null;
        HttpResponse response = null;
        Authorization.httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        Authorization.cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        Cookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("name", "value");
        Authorization.cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, Authorization.cookieStore);
        if (enter == 1 || enter == 0)
            httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.x-bikers.ru/enter.php");

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            if (enter == 1) {
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action2", "post"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name2", URLEncoder.encode(login, "utf-8")));
                Log.v("Login", URLEncoder.encode(login, "utf-8"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", URLEncoder.encode(password, "utf-8")));
                Log.v("Login", URLEncoder.encode(password, "utf-8"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("auto_enter", "y"));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                Log.v("", httppost.toString());
                response = (Authorization.httpClient.execute(httppost, localContext));

            } else if (enter == 0) {
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("act", "exit"));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                response = (Authorization.httpClient.execute(httppost, localContext));
            }

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStreamReader content = new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent(), "windows-1251");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(content);
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **CP1251** as your encoding charset in `URLEncoder.encode(password, "CP1251")`

Comment: Okay, now password is correct, but I still cant login((

Comment: Use this encoding for all the data you send to the server (all the URLEnconder... in your code).

Comment: Like so?

`nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action2", URLEncoder.encode("post", "windows-1251")));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name2", URLEncoder.encode(login, "windows-1251")));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", URLEncoder.encode(password, "windows-1251")));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("auto_enter", URLEncoder.encode("y", "windows-1251")));`

Comment: Yes, althought with string constants like "post" that are not russian character is not necessary, only variables, sorry. If after that you still cannot login try to put all the `new BasicNameValuePair("password", URLEncoder.encode(password, "utf-8"))` directly without encoding: `new BasicNameValuePair("password", password)` and then use the encoding in the UrlEncodedFormEntity: `new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "CP1251")`